# tensorflow in VS, already downloaded but not working

Tags: python, visual-studio, tensorflow, pip

Ive downloaded microsoft visual studio with python 3.6. I then downloaded tensorflow within VS using pip install within the python environment tools.
However when i run a script using tensorflow, i received an error:

```
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module(mname)
...
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

I therefore tried to download tensorflow using the command window, using the directory for python 3.6 downloaded alongside VS. However i received the following:

```
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.14.3)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.4.0 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.5.2.post1)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.1.6 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: astor>=0.6.0 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: gast>=0.2.0 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.8.6 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from protobuf>=3.4.0->tensorflow) (39.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach==1.5.0 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0->tensorflow) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.10 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0->tensorflow) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: html5lib==0.9999999 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0->tensorflow) (0.9999999)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<1.9.0,>=1.8.0->tensorflow) (2.6.11)
```

This leads me to believe that i have successfully downloaded tensorflow however am unable to access it? 
i tried to run a python shell to test the download by importing tensorflow as tf.

```
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
>>>
```

many thanks for all your help!!

Answer (score 1):

On Windows and using python v3.6.x 
ensure that when you install tensorflow you use

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

for cpu only support...or

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

if you have a supported gpu.

Also ensure that you run any verification tests outside of the python source directory tree.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your suggestion and received the error; Requirement not upgraded as not directly required. it looks like i already have tensorflow on the system!

Comment: Great.  Did you perform the import test you used earlier to confirm?

Comment: hi, yes i did and still received the same error which i posted in the original question!

Comment: please try the same test...but ensure that you are in a command shell at your home directory (not within the python source tree) when you first enter python.

Comment: thanks, i was running the test in the python source tree as i seem to receive an error when run in other locations: 'import' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: thanks.  I adjusted the answer to include that conditional warning.